# Touchpad not working after suspend on Asus A450L

Tags: touchpad, suspend, asus, 15.04

I recently change laptop to asus A450L and install latest ubuntu 15.04, there is one annoying bug, touchpad not working after suspend, and need to reboot to make it working again.

Touchpad not present in xinput after suspend, this is my xinput before suspend :

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

this after :

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

using this trick working before suspend but not working after suspend:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Is there any other workaround ?

[update]

And it's even working again after hibernate (suspend on disk).

```
:~$ dmesg | grep serio1
[    1.294732] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=10 00 64, EC=10 00 64
[    1.793203] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f01)
[    1.806832] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x15, 0x0c.
[    1.875780] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
...after suspend no additional output.
...after hibernate touchpad redetected again.
[ 2704.226793] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=10 00 64, EC=10 00 64
[ 2704.725799] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f01)
[ 2704.739412] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x15, 0x0c.
[ 2704.808346] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input20
```

Comment: So, this problem doesn't affect you anymore in most recent kernels/ubuntu? If this still happen, can you test this patch: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=224191 and just change some it to A450L? Please let me know if you have some problems. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm using the latest ubuntu 16.04 and sadly the problem still persist, and I don't know how to test your patch. Thanks!